# Is there a way to locate Google Chrome automatically - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer

### Problem

I have an `electron + puppeteer` application which uses the chrome on users computer (Windows and MacOS).

However the problems arises some users have chrome on different locations than set in my program, this leads to program not working completely.

### Objective

Is there any `NodeJs` module to detect chrome location on a PC automatically like registry or something? Or is there a way for puppeteer to detect chrome?

Comment: Found any way to do this?

Comment: @UmerUsman yes actually, just use the universal location for chrome ```C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe```

Answer (score 0):

You can use registry-js for this

```
const registry = require('registry-js');

const getChromePath = () => {
    try {
        const chromeRegistryKey = 'HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\App Paths\\chrome.exe';
        const chromeInfo = registry.getKey(chromeRegistryKey);

        if (chromeInfo.values && chromeInfo.values.length > 0) {
            const chromePath = chromeInfo.values.find((entry) => entry.name === 'Path');

            if (chromePath) {
                return chromePath.value;
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error retrieving Chrome path from registry:', error.message);
    }

    return null;
};

const chromePath = getChromePath();

if (chromePath) {
    console.log('Google Chrome is installed at:', chromePath);
} else {
    console.log('Google Chrome not found in the registry.');
}
```